# Buffered-Input Stream

Tags: java, io, stream

The below line is from the java documentation.

> "Buffered input streams read data from a memory area known as a buffer; the native input API is called only when the buffer is empty. Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a buffer, and the native output API is called only when the buffer is full."

Can some-one explain what does the line mean especially the last part of it ..

Comment: Why we use that is clear but couldn't understand this part of the sentence :   "Similarly, buffered output streams write data to a buffer, and the native output API is called only when the buffer is full."

Comment: Your data is written into a buffer in memory. It is only written to native output (which might be hard drive, network io, etc.) when the buffer is full. Usually, you can call `flush` to force the data to be written to the output before the buffer getting filled.

Comment: "Only if the buffer is full then the data will be written" thanks @Ervin Szilagyi understood that  but  what if we don't flush the partially-filled buffer ?

Comment: Depending on your system, the data might get simply lost.